# Chosing points so that $5$ tangents determine a conic

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

On this [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) it says, that we can make a conic with five tangents. I know how to construct a conic with five points, so I am wondering, how do we determine which point from tangents do we use. I know, that we cannot take three collinear points (so we cannot choose the intersections), but other than that, what are our restraints?

Comment: I can't seem to find my copy, but Dorrie is good on specific constructions https://store.doverpublications.com/0486613488.html

Comment: The contruction in Dorrie is online at https://archive.org/details/100GreatProblemsOfElementaryMathematicsDoverHeinrichDrrie/page/n281

Comment: Working algebraically, you can construct the matrix of the _dual conic_ directly from the lines and then compute its adjoint to get the conic. The elements of $\mathbb R^3$ that represent the lines are therefore subject to the same constraints that five points would be. So, for instance, no three of the lines can be coincident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Brianchon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem) as in the following diagram:

[image]

If $F$ is the point of contact of the tangent $CD$, then by Brianchon's theorem the three diagonals of the hexagon $ABCFDE$ are concurrent at a point $O$.

So we can intersect $BD$ and $CE$ to find $O$, and the contact point $F$ lies on the line $AO$.  Similarly we can find the four other contact points.

This gives us five points, from which we can construct the conic.